# Blockchain ideal consensus mechanism for Dapps used mostly on phones

Tags: blockchain, consensus

If we have an DApp that is running on a private chain, and mostly used by people on their phone. Let's say the application let's people exchange goods for tokens (basically an online platform). I see the advantage of implementing blockchain for two reasons: lower transaction fee / higher speed, and to be able to guarantee vendors certification.
Now what would be the ideal consensus mechanism, given users are using their phone, therefore low processing power. Allowing people to confirm transactions using their phone would make the chain an easy target for 51% attack (as it would require little processing power). Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the scenario of phones as light nodes and factoring in the security challenges poised by 51% attacks, and looking at the need for providing vendor certification, a consensus algorithm like delegated proof of stake or proof of authority looks relevant for the following reasons.

In proof of authority, mining of blocks is not a necessary pre-condition and hence you can use mobile phones as the light nodes.

In proof of stake, the cost for 51% attack is substantial and inhibitive.

If we consider delegated proof of stake, the delegation time can be used as a check and balance for the leader to route the incoming proposals to the relevant node. There could be one device or a machine with good computing capacity which can act as a leader to other mobile phone based nodes.

If transaction fee and the transaction speed are constraints, you need to consider a Blockchain platform other than ethereum for proof of authority or proof of stake based implementation.